# Opencv library files cannot find in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to develop a simple c++ project which uses opencv.I followed http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html website. 
But eclipse shows errors like

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_photo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_stitching
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_superres
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_ts
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_video
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_videostab
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_calib3d
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_contrib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_ocl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_flann
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_gpu
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_highgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_imgproc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_legacy
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_ml
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_nonfree
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_objdetect
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MyProject] Error 1`
```

I have included libraries and their paths in the following ways.

Project–>Properties

In C/C++ Build ->Settings.

```
In GCC C++ Compiler ->Includes. 
In Include paths(-l) I have added /usr/local/include/opencv.

In GCC C++ Linker 
I have added the path (-L) as /usr/local/lib and also library names.
```

Can anyone please tell me what the reason for this errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add the library names without the prefix 'lib'